# How to write a complex function for binding on a global hotkey?

Tags: key-bindings, org-clock

I would like to set a global hotkey in Emacs to perform a `org-clock-in` for a defined task in a defined file. This means that I have to open the file `~/org/main.org`, then go to the beginning of the buffer, then find the first occurrence of "Some Task", then go to the beginning of the line and running `org-clock-in` and then save the file. At the same time I must remain in the current buffer at the cursor position. How can I do this?

Comment: Will this work if I write such a function? I think opening the file in the buffer will transfer me from my current buffer

Comment: I've never seen examples of similar behavior. Can you show how to implement such things?

Comment: Yes, I'm interesting how to write such a function.

Comment: use `save-excursion` (see [(eintr) save-excursion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/save_002dexcursion.html), [(elisp) Excursions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably look at the documentation of [orgmode agenda views](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-views.html#Agenda-views) before coding your own todo list.
There is already a global [TODO list](http://orgmode.org/manual/Global-TODO-list.html) available.
See also the variable [`org-agenda-files`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-files.html).

Nevertheless, the following example code would do what you want. You can paste it into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

```el
(defvar valeriy-org-main-file "~/org/main.org"
  "My main org file.")

(defun valeriy-org-clock-in (task)
  "Clock in for TASK in `valeriy-org-main-file'."
  (interactive "sTask: ")
  (assert (file-readable-p valeriy-org-main-file) nil "File %s not existing." valeriy-org-main-file)
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect valeriy-org-main-file)
    (save-excursion
      (let ((pos (org-find-exact-headline-in-buffer task)))
        (assert pos nil "Task %s not found in file %s." task valeriy-org-main-file)
        (goto-char pos)
        (org-clock-in)
        ;; maybe... (save-buffer)
        ))))


(global-set-key (kbd "C-c i") #'valeriy-org-clock-in)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! =) I think it would be a good example for that, so I was able the next time to write something myself.